# Table being truncated when CSS-styled but displays fully (is scrollable) without CSS

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

My PHP app generates an HTML-formatted report which displays well with raw HTML markup on a mobile screen as seen below:

[image]
[image]

I got some CSS code off the web to make the table look nicer. It displays nicely but  without permitting left-right scrolling so it is not useful.

[image]

I would be grateful for any pointers from CSS/ HTML experts what to tweak in the code to allow this which is as follows:

```
$dumpout = "<html>
            <head>
              <meta content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\"
              http-equiv=\"content-type\">
              <style>
                .datagrid table { border-collapse: collapse; text-align: left; width: 100%; } .datagrid {font: normal 12px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: #fff; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #006699; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; }.datagrid table td, .datagrid table th { padding: 3px 10px;word-wrap:break-word; }.datagrid table thead th {background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #006699), color-stop(1, #00557F) );background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #006699 5%, #00557F 100% );filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#006699', endColorstr='#00557F');background-color:#006699; color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; border-left: 1px solid #0070A8; } .datagrid table thead th:first-child { border: none; }.datagrid table tbody td { color: #00496B; border-left: 1px solid #E1EEF4;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal; }.datagrid table tbody .alt td { background: #E1EEF4; color: #00496B; }.datagrid table tbody td:first-child { border-left: none; }.datagrid table tbody tr:last-child td { border-bottom: none; }.datagrid table tfoot td div { border-top: 1px solid #006699;background: #E1EEF4;} .datagrid table tfoot td { padding: 0; font-size: 12px } .datagrid table tfoot td div{ padding: 2px; }.datagrid table tfoot td ul { margin: 0; padding:0; list-style: none; text-align: right; }.datagrid table tfoot  li { display: inline; }.datagrid table tfoot li a { text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;  padding: 2px 8px; margin: 1px;color: #FFFFFF;border: 1px solid #006699;-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #006699), color-stop(1, #00557F) );background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #006699 5%, #00557F 100% );filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#006699', endColorstr='#00557F');background-color:#006699; }.datagrid table tfoot ul.active, .datagrid table tfoot ul a:hover { text-decoration: none;border-color: #006699; color: #FFFFFF; background: none; background-color:#00557F;}
              </style>
              <title></title>
            </head>
                <body> 
                As at $nowdt, Sales checks have been done on the following salesmen for $RunDate:
                <div class=\"datagrid\">
                <table style=\"text-align: left;\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"2\">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th align=\"right\">#</th>
                      <th align=\"right\">Salesman</th>
                      <th align=\"right\">Prior Check Date</th>
                      <th align=\"right\">Stock Found Now</th>
                      <th align=\"right\">Value Sold</th>
                      <th align=\"right\">Remittances</th>
                      <th align=\"right\">Excess/(Shortage)</th>
                      <th align=\"right\">Cumulative</th>
                    </tr></thead><tbody>";

while(!$rs->EOF)
{
    $count++;
    if ( !($count%2)) { $dumpout = $dumpout."<tr class=\"alt\">
                            <td align=\"right\">$count</td>"; }
        else {
        $dumpout = $dumpout."<tr>
                            <td align=\"right\">$count</td>"; }


    $dumpout = $dumpout."<td align=\"right\">$smname</td>";

    $dumpout = $dumpout."<td align=\"right\">$lastdate</td>";

$dumpout = $dumpout."<td align=\"right\">$scurrval</td>";

    $dumpout = $dumpout."<td align=\"right\">$ssoldval</td>";


    $dumpout = $dumpout."<td align=\"right\">$sremitval</td>";

    $dumpout = $dumpout."<td align=\"right\"><b>$sdiff</b></td>";

    $dumpout = $dumpout."<td align=\"right\"><b>$scdiff</b></td>";

    $rs->MoveNext();
}
$rs->Close();

$dumpout = $dumpout."</tr>
<tr>
  <td align=\"right\"></td>
  <td align=\"right\"></td>
  <td align=\"right\"><b>Totals</b></td>
  <td align=\"right\"><b>$stotvalf</b></td>
  <td align=\"right\"><b>$stotvals</b></td>
  <td align=\"right\"><b>$stotremit</b></td>
  <td align=\"right\"><b>$stotdiff</b></td>
  <td align=\"right\"><b>$sctotdiff</b></td>
</tr><br/><br/>
```

";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css you need to set the `overflow: hidden` to `overflow: scroll`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `overflow: scroll` parameter.

You may wish to set only `overflow-x: scroll` to not have the vertical axis scrolling.

You will also want to set the width if you are adding a scrollbar, otherwise it will not be visible.

So your final code might be:

```
.datagrid {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Some extra reading on overflow-x here: [CSS3 Overflow x](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp)